# Minimize one window and another one shows

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I've got a Winforms .net C# app. One of my forms (`form1`) creates another form (`form2`). I minimize `form1` down into the task bar (Win7). When I minimize `form2`, it minimizes OK but then `form1` shows (un-minimizes itself).

Here is the line of code:

```
frmForm2 = new MatrixForm(this);
frmForm2.Show();
```

What could be causing `form1` to show itself?

Comment: Show the code you use to show form2. Is it show() or ShowDialog()

Comment: frmForm2 = new MatrixForm(this);
    frmForm2.Show();

Comment: Do you minimize Form1 by code when you show form2?

Comment: Can u update the question with the code where u show, minimize and areas which u might think will cause the issue.

Comment: Paste all the codes so we can help

Comment: Your explanation is not enough. We need to know certain things to help you. Whether you are trying to minimize by code or by minimize button, whether you are trying to minimize parent form by code, showing up the new form as dialog and things like that

Answer (score 1):

Well after 'form1' minimizes, minimize 'form2' by this:

```
form2.WindowState = FormWindowState.Minimized;
```

I don't know the cause but this will help you. And if this din't help you then please don't give me negative vote. Tell me I'll try to solve it.

Comment: I minimize form2 by clicking on the minimize button in the upper right corner of the form. That is supposed to minimize the form (right?). I don't down vote anyone...you're here trying to help me.

Comment: I've written that code that as soon as form2 unminimizes it minimizes. And it will look like that it had not inminimized.

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to say ??

Comment: Sorry, I am unable to help you :(, but you should show your code.

Comment: I *did* show my code. You asked me to show you how I created the form and I showed you: frmForm2 = new MatrixForm(this); frmForm2.Show();

Comment: You got me to looking deeper at my code...I had some code that was calling form1.show() and I didn't realize it. I removed it and now it doesn't pop up. Thanks...

Comment: I am happy to help you. And I am also happy because you din't vote me down.